# SSH Key auth when home directory is symbolic link

Tags: linux, ssh, symbolic-link

The home directories on a server are mounted at `/mnt/Storage/Home`, and I have a symlink at `/srv/Home` pointing to that directory.  I can log into accounts on it and the home directory works fine, but I cannot use my ssh key to login.  It prompts me for a password instead.

I checked permissions on the .ssh directory and files and they're set correctly, but it still doesn't work.

```
drwx------  2 cclloyd cclloyd    6 Apr 13  2019 .
drwxrw---- 30 cclloyd cclloyd   55 Sep 17 01:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 cclloyd cclloyd 1616 Apr 13  2019 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 cclloyd cclloyd 1675 Sep 18  2018 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 cclloyd cclloyd  415 Sep 18  2018 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 cclloyd cclloyd 1110 Oct 13 03:12 known_hosts
```

Is there a way to get SSH keys to work with symbolic links?

Comment: Check the syslog on the server to see if sshd is logging any complaints about your home directory. It'd be helpful to know what exact message you're getting, if any.

Comment: @Kenster `Nov 12 02:44:26 singularity sshd[11731]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /mnt/Storagea/Home/cclloyd`.  Turns out your home directory needs to be `700` or else it won't work.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I believe your home directory can't be group- or world-writable. 755 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out your home directory itself also needs to be `700` or else it won't work.  Full required permissions below.

```
drwx------ .
drwx------ ..
-rw-r--r-- authorized_keys
-rw------- id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- known_hosts
```